# Update dict/json using date from other dict/json

Tags: python

How can I update `data_template` automatically using data from `result`?
My idea is to map fields like this:

```
map_fields = {
    "item_name": "itemName",
    "background_image": "backgroundImage",
    "back_item": "backItem"
}
```

but I'm not sure how to iterate over dict in this case to get excepted result

```
result = {
    "id": 10,
    "item_name": "name",
    "background_image": ""
    "back_item": "test",
}

data_template = {
    "itemName": "",
    "backgroundImage": "",
    "backItem": ""
}
```

My try:

```
for i in result.items():
    for field in map_fields.items():
        if i[0] == field[0]:
            data_template[field[1]] = i[1]

print data_template
```

Comment: Please include your attempts

Comment: @roganjosh done, can you please take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using you dictionary `map_fields`, I suggest you the following solution:

```
result = {
    "id": 10,
    "item_name": "name",
    "background_image": "",
    "back_item": "test",
}

data_template = {
    "itemName": "",
    "backgroundImage": "",
    "backItem": ""
}

map_fields = {
    "item_name": "itemName",
    "background_image": "backgroundImage",
    "back_item": "backItem"
}

for i in result.keys():
    if i in map_fields.keys():
        data_template[map_fields[i]] = result[i]

print(data_template)
```

Comment: Why `for i in result.keys()` and hit the `result` dictionary once again with `result[i]`? Why not `for k,v in result.items()`, and `data_template[map_fields[k]] = v` at the end?

Comment: @FatihAkici It is obviously a possibility. I preferred to suggest a code without the `items()` method to be as simple as possible for the requester who does not have a good command of dictionaries.

Comment: Sure, that's understandable. I'll add my humble opinion as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is good, but humbly, there is room to improve. First of all, don't call a dictionary's keys and values separately. You can do both in one call, by `result.items()`. Therefore the beginning of your original code draft is good.

Secondly, doing `if i in map_fields.keys()` is `O(n)`, unnecessarily expensive. If you do `if i in map_fields` it will not only become simpler, but also `O(1)`, hence more efficient! This trick will make a quadratic algorithm linear, which is better for obvious reasons.

So, the accepted answer is absolutely good, but a simpler and more efficient one is:

```
for k,v in result.items(): # Hit the dict once, and use k&v from now on
    if k in map_fields: # Don't lookup "in map_fields.keys()"", it is O(n)! Lookup of "in map_fields" is O(1)
        data_template[map_fields[k]] = v # Simple final assignment
```

Any comment to improve it further is, of course, welcome.

**Very Quick Edit:**

Actually you can get rid of the `if` altogether with exception handling.

```
for k,v in result.items(): # Hit the result dict once, and use k&v from now on
    try: data_template[map_fields[k]] = v # Will execute if k is in map_fields
    except: pass # Will not do anything if k is not in map_fields
```

For a brief guide to complexity of Python data structures: [TimeComplexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Comment: So kind of you, @LaurentH.! One of those Python masters can show up suddenly with some super-fancy itertools one-liner, from whom I'll learn a lot. :) SO is great for this constant learning opportunity, and awesome people like yourself!